# Query to determine column values shorter than normal

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql, teradata-covalent

I have a column whose values are supposed to be 11 numbers, however, some of them have less than 11 numbers. How can I write a query that will return all the values in this column that have less than 11 numbers. I am working in Teradata

Comment: What is the data type of the column? If it's a character string, are there characters other than digits present?

Comment: Hi Fred, data type is string and there are no other characters other than digits.

Comment: `where char_length(col) < 11`  to simply check for 11 characters. Or `where regexp_similar(col, '\d{11}' = 0` to check for exacty 11 digits. If it's a CHAR or there might be leading/trailing spaces switch add `TRIM`.